# VB.Net form- Check for duplicate words a user entered textbox

Tags: vb.net

Trying not to make this more complicated than it needs to be.

But I need to have a textbox and a button- when I click the button the code should count the words(i did this) and also display each word and how many times it appears in the string(aka textbox)

For example-  Hello my name is Tom, Tom is good

Listbox

Hello 1
My 1
Name 1
is 2
Tom 2
good 1

Any help is appreciated, thanks(this is not for a test etc)

Answer (score 1):

An alternate approach to `indexOf` would be to use a Dictionary to maintain the words and the counts. The benefit would be for large strings there would be less iterations than using `indexOf` as you could do something like:

1) Split the string (assuming this is just one loop through your string)

2) Iterate over the array once to count the number of occurrences of each word

Whereas with indexOf you'd need a fair few iterations to get through everything, depending on the size of your string

Dictionaries/Maps are nice data structures to know, in general. Here is a naive example as a console application:

```
Dim wordCount As Dictionary(Of String, Integer) = New Dictionary(Of String, Integer)()
Dim exampleString As String = "Hello my name is Tom, Tom is good"
Dim seperator() As String = {" ", ","}
Dim splitString() As String = exampleString.Split(seperator, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)

For Each s As String In splitString
    If wordCount.ContainsKey(s) Then
       wordCount(s) = wordCount(s) + 1
    Else
       wordCount(s) = 1
    End If
Next

For Each s As KeyValuePair(Of String, Integer) In wordCount
     Console.WriteLine(s.Key + " " + s.Value.ToString())
Next

Console.ReadLine()
```

But the code does look a bit more complicated, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [VB.net IndexOf](http://www.dotnetperls.com/indexof-vbnet) function with a loop to find the multiple instances of every word in the string and count them.

Just use a loop with the indexof function for every word you find in the whole string entered in the textbox.